# jquery click detect target child

Tags: jquery

I have a parent anchor link with many child span elements. When the user clicks the spans I perform different actions.

At the moment I simple turn off the default click behaviour, then bind my custom clicks. 
How can I merge this into one click function? Or is the correct way to handle?

```
<a href='http://www.test.com' target='_blank'><span>Link</span> other non clickable text</a>

// Bind menu items
$('a').each(function () {
  var $item = $(this);

  // Turn off default click
  $item.click(function(){
    return false;
  });

  // Click label text
  $item.children('span').eq(0).click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    if($item.attr("href")) {
      //window.location = '//' + $item.attr("href");
      alert('window.location');
    }  
  });

}); // each
```

http://jsbin.com/oFeMIPI/2/?html,js,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach using delegated event

```
$('a').on("click","span",function(e){
    //this now refers to the clicked span
    //do your logic here.

    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Think you may be over thinking it, simply do this:

```
$("a span").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); //Stop bubbling
    e.preventDefault(); //Dont execute default link behavior

    //Log stuff that you need!
    console.log("Link: " + $(this).parent().attr("href"));
    console.log("Span Text: " + $(this).text());
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Dhne7/

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('a').click(function(e){
    var $item = $(this), $target = $(e.target);

    if($target.is('span')){
        console.log($item.attr('href'))
    }


    return false;
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/KvfaM/)